# Setting up pythonpath in OS X

Tags: python, django, pythonpath

A new PHP developer here trying to learn Python/Django using the "Tango With Django" tutorial.

I'm up to section 2.2.2 where I have to set up the pythonpath and I'm having the following problem:

When I type the following in the terminal: `echo $pythonpath` I get a blank line instead of the correct path.

I followed the troubleshooting steps and found where the site-packages directory is:
`Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Per their instructions I updated my `.bashrc` file so it looks like this now:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

For a reason I don't understand I'm still getting a blank line when I `echo $pythonpath`.

Because I was having difficulty getting the `pythonpath` set up I skipped it, but then had problems installing Setuptools, Pip, and Django.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Any resources I can look at beside Tango with Django?

Comment: Try `set` rather than `echo $path`. This will list all environment variables available in the current shell.

Answer (score 6):

2 issues I can see -

1. $pythonpath and $PYTHONPATH are different. You want $PYTHONPATH. You will never use the lower-case version $pythonpath for anything, everything Python will 'respond' to will be in uppercase (by default)
2. By default, $PYTHONPATH is empty and only necessary to add additional paths to beyond the defaults. To see the default list you can run this command in a shell:

   ```py
   python -c 'import sys;print(sys.path)'
   ```

More than likely, the path you want will be in that list.

Thanks @martinanton for the python 3.0 update

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I forgot to mention that I was aware of the issue of case sensitivity and had tested both upper and lower case versions of $PYTHONPATH/$pythonpath.  Still getting a blank line when I try to echo the variable, but whatever I did to the path in the .bashrc file seems to work now and I was able to successfully install Pip and Setuptools.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: Nowadays it should be ```import sys;print(sys.path)```

Answer (score 4):

> For a reason I don't understand I'm still getting a blank line when I echo $pythonpath.

Environment variables are case sensitive. `PYTHONPATH` and `pythonpath` are different. So:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I forgot to mention that I was aware of the issue of case sensitivity and had tested both upper and lower case versions of $PYTHONPATH/$pythonpath.  Still getting a blank line when I try to echo the variable, but whatever I did to the path in the .bashrc file seems to work now and I was able to successfully install Pip and Setuptools.  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

First you should make sure that .bashrc is being executed when you open a new terminal screen.

If it doesn't, i recommend adding the following line to .bash_profile under your user home directory:
[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc

this line will make sure .bashrc exist, and if it does, it will execute it.
As mentioned, both .bash_profile and .bashrc should be located under /Users//

Hope this helps.
Meny